Cloud run Instance failed to start because permission was denied when creating an address in the subnetwork
I have been using Direct VPC egress in google cloud run since May 2, 2024 to access to Cloud SQL via private IP in the same network.
I have 2 environnments prod and staging, same configurations except min-instances (1 in prod and 0 in staging).
Subnet range = 10.2.0.0/22
Since June 18 I have been receiving these errors (only in staging) when the number of instances remains 0 for more than 20 minutes. (Only for the first request, in other cases works well)
Instance failed to start because permission was denied when creating an address in the subnetwork, Please check IAM settings.
Even though I assigned the networkUser role to the cloud run service agent.

Have you still available IPs in the target subnet?

Yes, target subnet range is 10.2.0.0/22, this subnet is only used for this Cloud Run Service, and we don't have a lot of traffic in staging.
Apparently the problem only happens when there is no ip address allocated

I have the same issue on production and development in my projects and it happens on some cloud run containers when they have already instances running, the when the number of instances remains 0 for more than 20 minutes. trail is not correct

If it works for a while, and then after a period of inactivity, no longer works, it's platform issue and you have to open a case to Google.

I've contacted GoogleCloud support.
The problem with PERMISSION_DENIED errors in the IP allocation of Serverless Direct VPC subnets appears to have been an error caused by a bug on the GoogleCloud side.
The product team has now finished restoring the Direct VPC service so that it can be provisioned normally, and there is no possibility of a recurrence.

https://support.cloud.google.com/portal/system-status
(Cloud Run customers using Direct VPC egress may see intermittent failures with deploying new revisions and autoscaling)
